How to cplot() a conditional function
I want to plot this function defined on complex numbers: if floor(Re(z))%2==0, f(z)=z else f(z)=sin(z)
I tried to code this:
import cplot
import math
import numpy as np

def f(z):
    if math.floor(np.real(z)[0])%2==0:
        res =z
    else:
        res=np.sin(z)  
    return res

plt = cplot.plot(f, (-10, +10, 3000), (-10, 10, 3000),5)
plt.show()

But it didn't work, the program completely ignores the existence of the sin function and I don't know why.

I thought this was because of my usage of math. and np. so I tested a simpler function:
if Re(z)>=0, f(z) =z, else f(z)= sin(z)
import cplot
import numpy as np

def f(z):
    if np.real(z)[0]>=0:
        res =z
    else:
        res=np.sin(z)  
    return res

plt = cplot.plot(f, (-10, +10, 3000), (-10, 10, 3000),5)
plt.show()

This time the existence of z was completely ignored.

I thought maybe the problem came from the [0] in np.real(z)[0] but removing it would yield an error

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I used them and the result is still the same, it completely ignores z in my second code, also the problem seems to be in the > sign; if I change it to < it completely ignores the sin.

"completely ignore the existence of the sin function": what do you mean with "ignore"? Do you mean a statement is not executed? What is the result of your debugging session?

@trincot It plot the other function (z) and didn't plot the sin at all as if I never wrote it.

What happens when you run this in a debugger and set breakpoints and inspect variables? Surely you can monitor what exactly executes in f?

The function you plot should return an array of results, not just the static result for the first item in the input array.
I'm not a Numpy person, but based on Applying a function along a numpy array I would try something like
def f(x):
    if np.real(x) >= 0:
        res = x
    else:
        res = np.sin(x)  
    return res

f_v = np.vectorize(f)
plt = cplot.plot(f_v, (-10, +10, 3000), (-10, 10, 3000),5)
plt.show()

I'm sure this could be rewritten more elegantly but at least this should show the direction.

There is a a problem in how you are treating z. You are treating it as a regular array and not as a complex number. So, here is how it should possibly be
def f(z):
   if np.floor(z.real) % 2 == 0:
       res = z
   else:
        res = np.sin(z)
   return res

